# How to return php value by javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some php data like $total_post ,$categories, $user which is coming from db.

> I want to create function like this.. I don't know if it's correct or
>   not.. This is like i just want..

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ 
  return "<?php  echo $total_post; ?>";
};

var barChartData = {
  labels : ["Active Posts","catagories", "User", "Comments","current online" ],
  datasets : [
    {
      fillColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.2)",
      strokeColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.8)",
      highlightFill : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.75)",
      highlightStroke : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
      data : [ randomScalingFactor() , 400, 300, 550,895]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does the code work?

Comment: Providing the above code exists within a .php file and is parsed, that should work, are you getting any errors at all? What result are you getting?

Comment: i don't get any error on this page but don't show any graph .. but when i try to view my page source and i got  the return value from function  (return "26") but the data : [ randomScalingFactor() , 400, 300, 550,895].. show this

Comment: yes... some think like that...Jose Manuel Abarca Rodriguez

Comment: I don't see any wrong in your code other then randomScaleingFactor should maybe return a Number instead of a string..? Anyway... I believe there is something else thats breaks your code

Comment: Just a shortcut tip... `<?= $total_post ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will work, after php compile the page you will have this:

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ 
     return "total_post_value";
};
```

You also may do something like this:

```
var randomScalingFactor = "<?php  echo $total_post; ?>";
```

So you don't need a function. But it can be a bit nasty while your project will grow, so I suggest create list of needed front end parameters in the site head something like that:

```
<head>
    <div id="back-end-parameters">
        <div id="total-post"><?php echo $total_post; ?></div>
    </div>
</head>
<footer>
   <script>
       var total_post = document.getElementById('total-post').innerHtml;
   </script>
</footer>
```

Comment: actually i got the value by calling  like var randomScalingFactor = "26"  but i want this 26 int value should set on my data:[ 26, ..... ] so that the full bar chart load on the screen ..tnx @Roman

Answer (score 0):

It's work at last.. thx guys try to help me

```
                var barChartData = {
                    labels : ["Active Posts","catagories", "User", "Comments","current online" ],
                    datasets : [
                        {
                            fillColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.2)",
                            strokeColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.8)",
                            highlightFill : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.75)",
                            highlightStroke : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                            data : [<?php echo $postCount; ?>, <?php echo $categoryCount; ?>, <?php echo $userCount ;?>, <?php echo $commentCount; ?>, 2 ]
                        }
                    ]

                }
```

it doesn't even need to declare a variable..